# Org Agenda schedule number of hours allocated to a task

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to tell Org Agenda to schedule X number of hours for a task without a specific start-end time? Presently, the standard format is this: `SCHEDULED: <2019-06-20 Thu 9:00-12:00>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to be using an [effort estimate](https://orgmode.org/manual/Effort-estimates.html) instead of a scheduled time?

An effort estimate is a property, stored in the property drawer, like this:

```
* TODO Something that can be done in 5 minutes
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Effort:   0:05
  :END:
```

Effort estimates are completely separate from scheduled or deadline times, and describe how long a task might take, rather than when it should be done.

Typically, estimates are added to a task with the `C-c C-x e` sequence.  If you have effort values that you use frequently, you can put a line like

```
#+PROPERTY: Effort_ALL 0 0:10 0:20 0:30 1:00 2:00 4:00 6:00 8:00
```

at the top of your org file, and then `S-<left>` and `S-<right>` will cycle through those values whenever you're prompted for an effort.

You may wish to check out a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeAtCVZpHCg) on the subject:

```
* TODO watch org mode tutorial on effort estimates
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Effort:   0:10
  :END:
  [[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeAtCVZpHCg][OrgMode E04S05: Effort estimates]]
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is pretty close to what I had in mind. How is it utilized? I don't really get a good idea of it from reading the org manual. I need a working example.

Comment: @jeffkowalski: this looks more like a comment than an answer. You might want to expand it to something beyond just a link and answer the OP's question in the previous comment as well. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help menu for more guidance.

Comment: @NickD, edited the answer to expand the content.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Very nice - thanks!